# Single evaluation for using exponential sampling until past a point

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-process, simulation

I am trying to improve an algorithm that looks like the following (and am getting stumped): I am provided with a starting time, rate, and a target time. I then use an exponential distribution to generate times with the given rate, summing them, until I get a time greater then the target time, which I return. In code, it looks like this:

```
def generateTime(start, rate, target):
    current = start
    while(current < target):
        current += (-1.0/rate)*log(random()) # where random returns [0, 1)
    return current
```

My intuition tells me there is some way to do this without having to to do the loop though, and to just use a closed form solution that does not have a loop, which might be run once, or many thousands of times, depending on the parameters of the simulation. Does such a better solution exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: about algorithms someone may help you,but for programmers there is different site,link of  which i gave you

Comment: first of all  what if  instead of  $-1.0$ use plus and also instead of  log use  simple random?what this code is doing is simple  transform from $-$  to plus $+$  by using multiplication of two minus.just use one plus.what will be different?without loop?i dont think that there  we can use another algorithm without loop.

Comment: please see my solution if works?

Comment: What my code should be doing is sampling from an exponential distribution repeatedly until it reaches some sort of goal post, and then returning that value. I do indeed have some minor simplifications I could make, like current-=log(random())/rate, but that would not result in almost any change in the actual runtime speed. And it is not really a subtraction, because log of a number between 0 and 1 is negative. An algorithm might not be possible like what I am looking for (I was not able to find one, but that is not exactly a proof :D).

Comment: Also, A+=B is in python equivalent to A:=A+B, in case that was not clear. I probably should no use syntactic sugar in something intended to be pseudo-code.